# Cannot set property 'X' of undefined when trying to assign a value

Tags: javascript, node.js

If your objective here is [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property), then go check that question.

If you are perplexed why the JavaScript engine says a variable is undefined when you are trying to access one of its properties, then you probably did the same silly mistake as I did. Read on and check the accepted answer.

---

I have the following bit of code which produces an error:

File `lib.js`:

```
var Lib;

(function() {
    var X = "X";        
    Lib.X = X;
})();

module.exports = Lib;
```

When this is run on command line:

```
$ node lib.js
```

Node.js produces following error:

```
lib.js:4
    Lib.X = X;
       ^
TypeError: Cannot set property 'X' of undefined
    at <path>\lib.js:4:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (<path>\lib.js:
16:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:484:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:190:38)
```

I can see that the problem is in the statement `Lib.X = X;`. But I am not sure if that line breaks any syntax/semantic rules. I understand this line as: assign `function X` to property `X` of variable `Lib`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @downvoter: Care to explain why? Not really interested about reps. But does this show no research effort? Or is it unclear? Or useless? :D

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this does seem to be an on-topic, clear question - even if it was a simple overlooked issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Comment: @Liam: Not really. Yes, no need to keep this open, but this has nothing to do with the linked question. This is a silly mistake and should be categorized as typographical error (If I remember correctly there's a closing category for that, but I cannot find it in close votes).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a silly mistake, and thus should be closed. This has nothing to do with the linked (supposedly duplicate) question.

Comment: This appears in search results that ultimately should be directed at the dupe target, as that gives better advice than this Q&A.

Comment: See https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=cannot+read+property+%27x%27+of+undefined+site%3Astackoverflow.com&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB785GB785&oq=cannot+read+property+%27x%27+of+undefined+site%3Astackoverflow.com&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.12500j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @Liam: Yeah OK fine I also voted to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Lib` is undefined. undefined is not an object, therefore you can't set any properties on it. You probably want this at the start of the file:

```
var Lib = {};
```

Comment: Ah! You beat me to it. It came to me seconds after I posted the question. Will be accepting this answer after the 15 minutes.

Comment: @Krumia Thanks, we all make silly mistakes from time to time :p

Answer (score 3):

Variable `Lib` is undefined, so you can't assign anything to it.

You need to define it first, as a minimal example:

```
var Lib = {};
```

Comment: Thanks @Brendan: +1ed. However, accepting simonzack's answer as he was few seconds earlier than you were. :)

Comment: @Krumia truly is a struggle to be the first. :) Thanks.